# CSS: Sticky footer and divs inside the footer. Float left

Tags: css, footer, sticky-footer

Maybe this is a problem with sticky footer, maybe not. Not quite sure. I want divs inside my footer to all line up side by side using `float:left`, but they seem to be stacking on top of each other, and I'm not sure why.

HTML:

```
 <div id="footer_container">
 <div id="footer_content">
 </div>
 <div id="footer_content">
 </div>..etc
```

CSS:

```
#footer_content {
font-size:18px;
    float:left;
padding:0 35px; 
color:#EEEEEE;
text-align:left;
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
}
```

Plus all the usual sticky footer stuff:

```
.wrapper {
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto -4em;
}
#footer, .push {
height: 175px;
}
#footer_content a{
   color:#989393;
}
#footer_container{
   width:1100px;
   height:175px;
}
```

Comment: Please consider using jsFiddle.net

Answer (score 2):

You cannot duplicate your element `id`'s.  Element `id`'s must be unique, but you use `id=footer_content` more than once.  Browsers tend to ignore subsequent elements with the same `id`.

Change them all to classes.

```
 <div class="footer_content">
 </div>

 <div class="footer_content">
 </div>
```

and

```
.footer_content {
    font-size:18px;
    float:left;
    padding:0 35px; 
    color:#EEEEEE;
    text-align:left;
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
}
```

Demo using your code with only that one id changed into a class...

http://jsfiddle.net/DRfuH/

Appears to be working as they are now side-by-side.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the footer_content to a class instead of an id.